# Cannot get shell script to send error message as mail body

Tags: bash, shell-script, mail-command

I have a shell script I want to email me when a particular command fails and send along the error message. Either it doesn't send an email at all, or it sends an email with an attachment named ATT000001.bin (in Outlook). I just want an email with the error in the body as plaintext.

Here's a snip of what I have at the moment:

```
msg=`scp -i $sshkeyfile $filename username@11.11.11.11 2>&1`
msg=`echo $msg | tr -d "\n\r"`

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  rm $filename
else
  echo $msg | mail -s "subject line" someone@somewhere.com
fi
```

The web says that return characters can cause Outlook to treat the string as an attachment; thus why I'm stripping out the return (I've confirmed it works by printing it to the console). As it stands, I'm not getting an email message at all.

I have tried every different way I've found on the web to pass the string to mail. I've tried sendmail. I either get no email or I get an email with an attachment.

What can I do to cause this string to be sent as the body of the email message? Thanks!

Comment: You need a NewLine (`^J`, `"\\r"`) at the very end of `$msg`

Comment: I added `msg="$msg"$'\r'` but I'm still not getting an email.